# Postman sending request hanging

Tags: mongodb, express, postman

I am new to Postman. I am unsure of why my postman is hanging when trying to get from "http://localhost:8001/application/cards". It's supposed to respond with an empty array but it just keeps sending request. It works for "http://localhost:8001" to which it does give me "Hello World!" but doesn't work when I add /application/cards. Is there new syntax update? I can give more information about my code if necessary.

```
...

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

...

app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('Hello World!'));

app.post('/application/cards', (req, res) => {
    const dbapplication = req.body;

    Cards.create(dbapplication, (err, data) => {
        if (err) 
        {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(201).send(data);
        }
    });
});

app.get('/application/cards', (req, res) => {
    Cards.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) 
        {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Note: /application/cards in my question was an example, but SpartanSwipe is actually my application.

Upon testing data using POST http://localhost:8001/application/cards, I got a 500 Internal Server Error after about 10 seconds.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test Name",
        "profPic": "https://as1.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/01/17/42/38/500_F_117423860_bApe5ResfiVkO0G0UlUjUVNpAtFUWYYy.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Nest Tame",
        "profPic": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/happy-university-college-student-thumbs-up-15010463.jpg"
    }
]
```

[image]

Here is my database .js for the cards

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const cardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    profPic: String
});

export default mongoose.model('cards', cardSchema);
```

Comment: can you provide postman screenshot?

Comment: FYI, `res.status(200)` is not necessary as 200 is already the default status.  You can just use `res.send(data)` directly and it will have a 200 status.

Comment: i think, your db connection and db code have error, thats why it raise 500 internal server error. you give code res.status(500).send(err); so it will raise error. please console.log(err) and read the error then fix that, try again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DB Connection is ok?? I think your issue lies in the structure of your code. According to the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), your first parameter should be an empty object followed by the callback to return all records like the example given below.

```
Cards.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) 
        {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
```

Example

```
Cards.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        
        res.status(200).send(docs);
 });
```

Comment: Just tried that and it still hangs. Do you know some ways to check if my database connection is okay?

Comment: Try replacing res.status with console logs, hit the route with Postman, and observe what happens in the express app CLI. Also, console log your req.body to make sure it's receiving your JSON data on POST.